# Declaring new variables or using references in functions?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, methods

When defining methods for a class, is it better to use members themselves or does assigning them to a new variable make it faster? Imagine, for instance in JavaScript the following method:

```
square: function() {
    var x = this.x;
    x *= x;
    return x;
}
```

or

```
square: function() {
    this.x *= this.x;
    return this.x;
}
```

Comment: In the second case you are mutating the value of `this.x`. In the first case you are not.

Comment: Wouldn't the first one be better as a one-liner: `return this.x * this.x;`? That avoids creating extra variables and doesn't do any assignments. (And as has been pointed out your second version doesn't do the same thing, so comparison between the two is not meaningful.)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the difference in speed will almost always be negligible, meaning that this is a [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), which should be avoided in favor of using whatever method is more maintainable.

However, in your particular case there is a major difference in functionality between the two `square` methods, as shown below.

```js
var a = {
    x: 2,
    square: function() {
        var x = this.x;
        x *= x;
        return x;
    }
}

console.log('Result of a.square():', a.square()); //Output is 4
console.log('After square, a.x is:', a.x); //Output is 2

var b = {
    x: 2,
    square: function() {
        this.x *= this.x;
        return this.x;
    }
}

console.log('Result of b.square():', b.square()); //Output is 4

//The difference is here: b.x will be 4 while a.x is still 2
console.log('After square, b.x is:', b.x); //Output is 4
```

The first `square` method will not update `this.x`, but the second method will. Use whichever version matches your intent. Simplified versions of each method are below, after eliminating the premature optimization. The gain in maintainability is clear.

First version (does not update `this.x`):

```
square: function() {
    return this.x * this.x;
}
```

Second version (does update `this.x`):

```
square: function() {
    return this.x *= this.x;
}
```